# Continuous time Markov chains and invariance principle

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes

This question may be elementary for experts

Let $\{\xi_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be an i.i.d random variables on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. We assume that the mean of $\xi_n$ is zero, and the variance is $1$. For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $t \ge 0$, we set
\begin{align*}
X_n&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \xi_k,\quad 
Y_t=X_{[t]}+(t-[t])\xi_{[t]+1}
\end{align*}
Here, $[\cdot]$ denotes the floor function. By the definition, $Y=\{Y_t\}_{t \ge 0}$ is the linear interpolation of the simple random walk $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$.
We define $Z_t^{(n)}=Y_{nt}/\sqrt{n}$, Then, each $\{Z_{t}^{(n)}\}_{t \ge 0}$ induces a probability measure on $C([0,\infty))$, the space of continuous functions on $[0,\infty).$ We denote by $P_n$ the probability measure. Donsker's invariance principle states that $\{P_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to the Wiener measure.

**My question**

We write $n^{-1}\mathbb{Z}=\{\cdots,-2/n,-1/n,0,1/n,2/n,\cdots\}$. Let $S^{(n)}=\{S_t^{(n)}\}_{t \ge 0}$ be a (**continuous time**) Markov chain on $n^{-1}\mathbb{Z}$. My question is the following:

**Are there "Donsker's invariance principles" for $\{S^{(n)}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ (or scaled $\{S^{(n)}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$) ?**

Because $\{S^{(n)}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are continuous time Markov chains, there is no interpolated process like $Y$.
Although the state space of each $S^{(n)}$ is $n^{-1}\mathbb{Z}$, this should be regarded as a jump process on $\mathbb{R}$. Then, each $S^{(n)}$ induces an probability measure  on $D([0,\infty))$, the space of right continuous functions on $[0,\infty)$ with finite left limits. Wiener measures are also regarded as a probability measure on $D([0,\infty))$.

Please let me know if you have any preceding results.

Comment: You can still interpolate linearly by discretizing time, prove the invariance principle in C for the interpolated process, and then show that the D distance between the interpolation and the original process converges to 0 as $n\to \infty$. You can look up general techniques in the book of Ethier and Kurtz, or for a different twist, Komorowsky, Landim and Olla's book.

Comment: @oferzeitouni Thank you for your comment. I see, that would work.